# rails console (`require': cannot load such file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

i am having problems with rails console, that send's me this error's

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:59:in `console'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /home/xploshioon/rails/mini_twitter/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

and i haved problems like that with other aplication but solved creating the app again. but now i have some code so i don't want to create this again.

anyone know what is the problem here?

i have linux mint 17 
ruby 
2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [i686-linux]
Rails 
4.1.8

Comment: Try bundle exec rails console

Comment: try gem install rb-readline, will resolve it

Comment: both solution the same, still with the problem, any other idea guys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with adding this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

Followed by:

```
bundle install
```

If this does not solve the issue, follow this:

Install readline:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

remove and re-install ruby

```
rvm remove 2.1.4    
rvm install 2.1.4
```

finally

```
bundle install
```

Comment: that work, no need to install libreadline-dev, was installed and no need to reinstall ruby, just rb-readline in my gemfile and work. thanks so much

Comment: thats great. I added those lines just to be sure that everything is in place. :)

Comment: nice, a +1 for you hehe